# share code between a rails helper and a background worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I have code in a rails helper that is being used in a view and i also have the same code in a background worker class.

How do i extract this code out into its own class or module to use for both the helper and background class?

Please can any one help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, code that needs to be shared between background tasks and rails goes logically in `lib/my_library.rb`. Just `require 'my_library'` in your controller and job files.

lib/my_library.rb:

```
class MyLibrary
    def self.do_something(foo)
    end
end
```

In app/jobs/my_job.rb:

```
require 'my_library'

# ...
MyLibrary.do_something( "x" )
```

Comment: hi eibjj      Please can you show me how to do this ?   Do you mean create a class called MyLibrary ?

Comment: yes, create a `class MyLibrary` or whatever and put some singleton/static methods on it: `def self.do_something`, etc.